# Keras LSTM for converting sentences to document context vector

Tags: python, keras, nltk, lstm, seq2seq

I read the following blog post and tried to implement it via Keras:
https://andriymulyar.com/blog/bert-document-classification

Now, Im quite new to Keras and I do not understand **how to use "seq2seq neural networks" to condens a sequence of subchunks (sentences) into a global context vector (document vector).** - via LSTM..

For example: I have 10 documents consisting of 100 sentences each and each sentence is represented by a 1x500 vector.
So the array would look like this:

```
X = np.array(Matrix).reshape(10, 100, 500) # reshape to 10 documents with 100 sequence of 500 features
```

So I know I want to train my network and take the last hidden-layer cause this one represents my document vector/global context vector.

However, the hardest part for me is to imagine the output vector.. do I just enumerate my documents

```
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = np.array(y)
```

or do I have to use one-hot-encoded output vectors:

```
yy = to_categorical(y)
```

or even something else..?

As far as I understand, the final model should look something like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(100,500)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(X, yy, epochs=100, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends only on the data you use:

For one-hot encoding use **Categorical Crossentropy Loss**.

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop')
```

For label encoding use **Sparse Categorical Crossentropy Loss**.

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop')
```

The base approach is the same at both version.
So if you have a **target data** as **y** like:

```
Class1 Class2 Class3
0      0      1
1      0      0
1      0      0
0      1      0
```

You should complile your model like:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop')
```

In contrary if you have a **target data** as **y** like:

```
labels
2
0
0
1
```

You should complile your model like:

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop')
```

The result and performance of your model will be the same only the memory usage can be affected.

Comment: Thanks, I see.. for one-hot-encoded label data it works now, but I also forgot to adjust to ```model.add(Dense(10)``` to reflect the 10 labels. But it still does not work for a target data that is just one output-vector ```y=[1,2,...10]```to reflect all documents.. I get following error (if done for 5 documents ```y=[1,2,3,4,5]``` ```InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 5 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).  Label values: 5
  [[{{node loss_15/dense_15_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]```

Comment: @Felix If the output Dense layer has 5 outputs it will except only labels in [0,1,2,3,4] as Python's  indexing is from `0`. So your labels should have these values, that is why the complaining. Please don't forget to accept my answer with check mark, if you are satisfied,